# How to create a user defined formulas instead of typing out long strings

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, user-defined-functions

I am trying to assign the following formulas that i would normally paste into a cell to a user defined formula.

=concatenate(text(A2,"000000"),"-",text(A3,"000"))

I need the text portion to format and get leading zeros up to 6 digits before the hyphen and up to 3 digits after the hyphen.
I wanted to assign it to Format(Selection1, Selection2) where selection 1 would be A2 and selection 2 would be A3 for example so that I could avoid having to type out that entire string all the time.

Comment: Where are you ultimately putting the result (formula, UDF, etc)? Why can't you fill right or down to achieve the additional formulas?

Comment: btw, `=TEXT(A2*10^3+A3, "000000-000")` may be a little less to type.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, i wanted to put the formula into a userdefined function so i could just use the function and select the two cells. Thanks very much for your help! i'm not 100% sure the logic behind why the multiplication works but i assume its specifically for formatting purposes! thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function blah(A, B)
    blah = Format(A, "000000") & "-" & Format(B, "000")
End Function
```

Comment: `blah = Format(A * 10 ^ 3 + B, "000000-000")`

Comment: thanks very much @tim williams, I feel like i was trying to over-complicate it by trying to set the input output as variants, integers etc. I appreciate the help!